# Using stopwords with Python's Sphinx module to change searchindex.js (not open search)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, stop-words

I'm creating docs with Python's Sphinx, and my question relates to searching generated docs (e.g with the rtd theme) and using stopwords to modify the searchindex.js file.

I'm not sure how or if Open Source Search Server is related to Sphinx doc gen, but I've tried the methods I could find via Google and those did not work. I'm not creating Apple Help, so that option in the conf.py file is not relevant.

Failed experiments: stopwords = /stopwords in conf.py

So: How does one use stopwords with a standard Sphinx doc gen project using the Read The Docs Theme (probably the same as any theme)? Is it possible?

Comment: Note that the Sphinx search engine ([tag:sphinx]) is unrelated to the Sphinx documentation tool ([tag:python-sphinx]).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So, is there a stopword feature for Sphinx docs? Would be surprised if there wasn't.

Comment: There are stopwords, but they are not easily configurable (as far as I know). https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/search/en.py#L16

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I added several hundred words to that file. Note that if there is a searchindex.js file in the output, the new stop words don't take effect. A new file is written, but the stop word additions are not used. I have had to manually delete searchindex.js for the changes to take effect.